# Custom row order in the output

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the rows in the result set of my query to follow the specific order of values that I am specifying in the `IN` clause.

This is my query:

```
SELECT rd.id,
       rd.room_no,
       rd.bed_one,
       rd.bed_two,
       rd.bed_count,
       ir.room_type_id,
       ir.prop_id 
FROM room_details rd 
   JOIN (inventory_rooms ir) 
WHERE ir.id=rd.inventory_type_id 
  AND ir.prop_id IN ('6966','9016','8900','15242');
```

This is the result set:

```
id   room_no     bed_one  bed_two  bed_count  room_type_id  prop_id  
---  ----------  -------  -------  ---------  ------------  -------
48   C- 202-01A  null     null     1          20            6966  
49   C- 202-02A  null     null     1          20            6966  
24   D-802 -A    null     null     1          20            9016  
25   D-802 -B    null     null     1          20            9016  
243  101         null     null     1          4             8900  
267  102-B       null     null     1          4             8900  
23   D-804 -C    C1       C2       2          21            9016  
39   D-805-A     A1       A2       2          21            9016
```

I want same `prop_id` values to stick together and follow the order as in the `IN` list. In particular, the last two rows should come together with the 3rd and 4th rows.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to provide the query that you are using.  It is also helpful to tag with the database you are using, to give samples of input data, and the results that you want.

Comment: How are you deciding the order?

Comment: Sorry guys let me give the query and result also :SELECT rd.id,rd.room_no,rd.bed_one,rd.bed_two,rd.bed_count,ir.room_type_id,ir.prop_id FROM room_details rd JOIN (inventory_rooms ir) WHERE ir.id=rd.inventory_type_id AND ir.prop_id IN  ('6966','9016','8900','15242')

Comment: My result is coming like this : my prop_id column is coming like this 6966,6966,6966,9016,9016,8900,15242,9016 so i want the result like this 6966,6966,6966,9016,9016,9016,8900,15242

Comment: @Sthita: please do not post SQL Statements in comments, edit your question. The query you posted is invalid, it is missing the join condition (no `ON ...` clause in your query)

Comment: "if i am doing order by id then the oder(sic) is changing" - I feel like I'm missing something huge here. You're applying an `ORDER BY` and yet you **don't** want the order to change?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes correct

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the `IN` clause to serve both as a filter and as a sorting specifier?

Comment: By the way, please specify the database system (and its version) that you are using.

Comment: @Andriy M : Yes,i am using Mysql

Comment: @Sthita: I've edited your question. Please take a look and feel free to add any corrections where I've missed the point.

Comment: @Andriy M :Its perfectly file, thanks.

Comment: @Downvoters: Please consider revisiting your downvotes in the light of the clarifications made to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you need a fairly arbitrary order on `SomeColumn`, you can hard code the order, like so:

```
SELECT id, someColumn
    FROM  `Table` 
    WHERE someColumn IN ('2','4','3') 
ORDER BY 
    CASE SomeColumn 
        WHEN '2' THEN 1 -- '2's come first
        WHEN '4' THEN 2 -- then '4's
        WHEN '3' THEN 3 -- then '3's
        ELSE 4 -- then everything else, etc
    END;
```

SqlFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e03f/1)

**Update for your new data / question**

(Note - MSSQL - MySql tag was only added later.)

You can use a `temp table` variation of @pdleorme's idea on creating an 'order' table. Since you want it dynamically, insert the filter values in the order in which you want the results sorted, like below. Note that the `where` clause is then no longer needed, because filtering will be implicit by the join to the temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpOrder
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), -- used to retain the order
    prop_id NVARCHAR(10)
);

-- Insert the filter columns values here, in the order in which you want to sort
INSERT INTO #tmpOrder(prop_id) VALUES ('6966'), ('9016'), ('8900'), ('15242');

SELECT rd.id,rd.room_no,rd.bed_one,rd.bed_two, -- ...
FROM room_details rd 
    JOIN inventory_rooms ir ON ir.id=rd.inventory_type_id 
    -- Where is No LONGER NEED WHERE ir.prop_id IN ('6966','9016', ...
    JOIN #tmpOrder t on t.prop_id = ir.prop_id 
ORDER BY t.ID ASC;
```

[Updated SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0befb/1)

Comment: StuartLC Thanks, its helping but problem is that How to make it dynamic means the In clause parameter counts are not always 3 , i am using a prepared statement from there these parameters are going to be passed so in this scinatio how i will put the Cases ?hope you got my problem ..

Comment: @Sthita I've updated the answer - use a temp table with an definite order to insert the filter columns in the same order you want the results to be sorted. I've used an identity column to guarantee the order.

Comment: @Sthita - my answer is for MSSQL - The MySql tag was added late.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an order table with :

```
order_table :
id | order
----------
 1 | 1
 2 | 3
 3 | 2
...
```

and do a join / order by

```
select id 
  from data_table,
       order_table
 where data_table.id = order_table.id
 order by order_table.order
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the query. Still, assuming you cannot use Order By clause as mentioned by you, there are 2 ways you can achieve this:

**FIrst Option**

Insert another Column in your table named "OrderByCol"

Now in your data, for eg:

```
Sr   OrderByCol   Col3 
2    1            xyz
2    1            abc
3    3            123
3    3            456
4    2            qwerty
4    2            123456
```

And then use the following query:

```
Select * from #table order by OrderByCol
```

**Second Option**

If you cannot insert Column, you can use UNION All operator

```
Select * from #table1 where SrNo=2
UNION all
Select * from #table1 where SrNo=4
UNION all
Select * from #table1 where SrNo=3
```

UNION all clause will group your results with the desired order.

First Option is any day better.